# Is it appropriate to flag a meta question for ♦ moderator attention because they are the only ones who can act on it?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

Almost 2 months ago, I posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217015/create-the-nivo-slider-tag-and-merge-nivo-nivoslider-with-it

Simply, the question asks for a ♦ moderator to allow the creation of the [nivo-slider](/questions/tagged/nivo-slider) tag. There currently is a [nivoslider](/questions/tagged/nivoslider) tag, but it doesn't follow naming conventions. (There is also another tag, [nivo](/questions/tagged/nivo), which needs to be merged as well.) It seems like a pretty simple task: create (or allow creation) of the new, hyphenated tag. I was going to then go through, myself, and start retagging questions to fix the naming issues and the duplicate tag issue.

The question got several upvotes, but no ♦ moderator response (as I assume they are the only ones who can make this tag request happen). I've burnt a bounty on it, and edited the question several times to push it back up and get attention, but no dice.

Today, I'm considering flagging the question for ♦ moderator attention, but this feels a little wrong to me. The question *does* need ♦ moderator attention, but not because the question is bad (which is what the flags are for).

**QUESTION:** Is it appropriate to flag for ♦ moderator attention? If not, what is the proper way to get a ♦ moderator attention to a task only they can resolve that seems to have been ignored for an extended period of time?

---

**EDIT:** I have permission to create new tags. However, because the tag is too similar to an existing tag, it has to be done by a ♦ moderator.
[image]

Comment: Moderators are not needed to create a tag...anyone with sufficient rep (btw, **you** have sufficient rep) to have the privilege can do that.  You even have enough rep to suggest tag synonyms, so there is no need at all to edit every single question using either of those tags, a synonym will do just fine.

Comment: Do you mean all (401) instances of the nivoslider tag must be changed to nivo-slider? This can be done manually, but as far as I know, moderators have a tool for that.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, but it can't be done manually since he can't create the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

By posting on Meta, you've already made moderators aware of it.  Reserve moderator flags for their intended purpose; to moderate posted content and user behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for and what I assumed was the case. I only asked because some rules are slightly bent on Meta. Can you elaborate how I can then bring more attention to my linked post? I don't feel like I'm asking a lot, and I am planning on spending time to improve those tags. However, I cannot get started without some moderator intervention. I feel like a bounty should have done it, but it still hasn't gotten the attention it needs.

Comment: Looks to me like you've already given it some additional attention.